# IntelliJ IDEA Error: Could not find or load main class GradleStart

Tags: java, intellij-idea, windows-10, minecraft

When trying to start my Minecraft client project, it comes up with the **Error: Could not find or load main class GradleStart**, it says this is caused by **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GradleStart**, does anyone know what this means?

**Error: Could not find or load main class GradleStart**
**Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GradleStart**

[image]

Comment: Do `./gradlew build` and `./gradlew runClient` work outside the IDE? Did you set up the workspace with `./gradlew idea`?

Answer (score 0):

Under "Edit Configurations" where the "Run Minecraft Client" is change from "Minecraft Modding" to Minecraft Modding.main.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTa0p.jpg